# How to make a transition between an asset image and an network image

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-animation

**How to make a transition between a local image and an image that comes from an internet server**  I would like the internet image to appear slowly.

> I'm trying various things, but this ultimately worked the best, although I still can't smoothly transition.

[image]

Comment: instead of posting an image, it is a good practice to post the code. It helps people to edit the code and give you the solution.

Comment: If one of the answer has helped you please consider upvoting

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to check  the [cached_network_image](https://pub.dev/packages/cached_network_image) package.

You can specify a placeholder widget which could be the local asset image, and the library will handle the loading and the animation for displaying the network image when it is ready.

Read the documentation for more customization.